# Bootstrap carousel with different size cards

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel faq, there are some boxes with different questions and answers, so the boxes are not the same size as you can see above:

[image]

My code is this one:

```
    <section id="faq" class="shadow-lg">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h3 class="font-weight-light">Faq</h3>
        <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
            <div id="recipeCarousel" class="col carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="row carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="card card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title">pergunta</h4>
                                    <p class="card-text">resposta</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="card card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title">pergunta</h4>
                                    <p class="card-text">resposta</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle"
                        aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle"
                        aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

css:

```
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
        display: flex;
    }
#faq{
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}

#faq h3{
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#faq .card{
    border-color: #216869;
    min-height: 400px;
}
#infos, #contato, #faq, #planos{
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #666666;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

I want the boxes to be at the same height, regardless of the size of the questions. Basically, I want all the boxes to be the same height as the largest.

Comment: Couldn't you use the ```min-height``` and ```min-width``` property here? Also could you post all of your code so I can fool around in the code?

Comment: it worked thankss, i tried before but wasnt working, but now i put on the card and not carousel-item

Comment: but don't have some way of get this dinamic? like get the the largest one and set on the others?